# Do we not normally use "also" in negative sentences?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

> Not only have I had enough **with** him, but I **also** don't care about him
> anymore.

My sentence above has been corrected for me like this:

> Not only have I had enough **of** him, but I also don't care about him
> anymore **either**.

It makes me think that the corrector doesn't suggest using **also** in negative sentences. Am I thinking that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually have enough "of" someone, not enough "with" him, so the first correction is good. However, there is no reason to add "either". In fact, it is redundant after "also". You could write:

> Not only have I had enough of him, but I also don't care about him anymore.

Or:

> Not only have I had enough of him, but I don't care about him anymore, either.

The first version maintains the common correlative pair "not only . . . but also". The second replaces "also" with "either".

You may be interested in this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/is-i-also-dont-know-less-correct-than-i-dont-know-either

Answer (score 1):

> but I also don't care about him anymore.

To my ears, this is grammatical, but would flow slightly better with an intensifier somewhere:

- but I also **just** don't care about him anymore.
- but I also don't care about him anymore **either**.
- but I also don't **really** care about him anymore.

In spoken English, I'd probably use all three, to be honest:

- but I also just don't really care about him anymore, either.